# How can I do multiple logical end for multiple system properties?

Tags: spring-el, junit-jupiter

I'm trying check existence of multiple system properties for `EnabledIf`.

When I do fo a single system property, it seems work.

```
@EnabledIf(expression = "#{systemProperties['some'] != null}")
```

But I failed for multiple system properties.

```
@EnabledIf(expression = "#{systemProperties['some'] != null} and " +
                        "#{systemProperties['other'] != null}")
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `and` needs to be within the expression:

```
@EnabledIf("#{systemProperties['some'] != null and "
           + "systemProperties['other'] != null}")
```